# IBM PowerVM LPAR shows 16cpu despite 4 cpu allocation

Tags: virtual-machines

Environment:
IBM PowerVM 8
IOS version 2.2.3.50

When I create an LPAR (Virtual Machine), I allocate 4 shared CPU's.
I then install Redhat 6.6 p64.
Nproc shows 16 CPUs.

On a different machine, I allocate 1 shared CPU.
I then install Redhat 6.6 p64.
nproc show 4 CPUs.

Why does the OS report 4 times the processor I specify when setting up the machine?

Comment: For shared CPUs there are two numbers: how much processing power a VM gets and how many processors a VM 'sees'. The former is commonly called the CPU entitlement and the latter vCPU allocation. A description of it in the AIX docs: [Power VM Concepts](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-powervm-portal/#2.PowerVMconcepts|outline).

Comment: Thanks for the Doc link.  My VM setup screen, and existing VM config screen are different than what is in this doc. I see No select-able vCPU option.  When i set up a new VM, I'm instructed some things, like .1 shared process = 1 virtual processor, but even if I create a new VM with .2 processors, the OS reports 4 processors.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are running SMT 4. The OS has 4 hardware threads to schedule on with one virtual processor, even if the hypervisor will only schedule say 0.2 cores worth of time slices.

Counting hardware threads as "CPUs" is not just in Linux, AIX tools also do that.